# How to import a specific table from a .sql file in DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I accidentally `DROP` a column from a table in a database. I want to restore that column, luckily I have an .sql file of a backup this morning. I use DataGrip.

Is there a way to import only that table from the .sql file? That way I will not have to reset all other tables too (that other people are working on).

Comment: You can copy relevant part of your backup file to new one and use it for restore only one table

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was

- create a temporary database:
  `mysqladmin -u root -p create temp`
- restore the .sql into it `mysql -u root -p restore < mydump.sql`
- dump the specific table `mysqldump -u root -p restore mytable > mytable.sql`

Import the file in DataGrip, right-click the tab and press 'Run...' and set your database as target.